# Is there a function to add column in data (rbind)

Tags: r, rbind

I would like to add 3 columns  below a data who exist.   But the problem is  that My first data got 10 column  with (id,num, x, xx, xxx, xxx, xxx, .....)
and the second data got only 3 column with (id,num, x)

I would like to put the second data in first data and for that I would like to create 7 new column (only `NA`)  to use `rbind`.

For example I have data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, num = 6:10, V1 = 11:15, V2 = 16:20)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 6:10, num = 11:15)
```

I wanted to get expected output:

```
   id num V1 V2
1   1   6 11 16
2   2   7 12 17
3   3   8 13 18
4   4   9 14 19
5   5  10 15 20
6   6  11 NA NA
7   7  12 NA NA
8   8  13 NA NA
9   9  14 NA NA
10 10  15 NA NA
```

I tried to create a matrix with only `NA` and I research on the net but I found nothing

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I've improved your question by adding sample data and expected output. Feel free to edit it even further.

Answer (score 2):

The base R function `rbind` requires that all data.frames being bind together have the same number of columns and names. This would require either adding the excess columns to the smaller dataframe with `NA` rows or another function that allows non-matching columns. Fortunately, there is a function called `bind_rows` from `dplyr` that does exactly that:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

**Output:**

```
> rbind(df1, df2)
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

> dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)
   id num V1 V2
1   1   6 11 16
2   2   7 12 17
3   3   8 13 18
4   4   9 14 19
5   5  10 15 20
6   6  11 NA NA
7   7  12 NA NA
8   8  13 NA NA
9   9  14 NA NA
10 10  15 NA NA
```

Comment: @Raph Glad that this helped. If you think that this solution answers your question. Please accept it so others can see.

Answer (score 0):

This is an *outer join*---it just happens to be one where none of the IDs overlap.

```
merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
   id num V1 V2
1   1   6 11 16
2   2   7 12 17
3   3   8 13 18
4   4   9 14 19
5   5  10 15 20
6   6  11 NA NA
7   7  12 NA NA
8   8  13 NA NA
9   9  14 NA NA
10 10  15 NA NA
```

See the FAQ on [how to merge (join) data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/903061) for context and more options.

Comment: Note that this gives different output than a row bind if `id` and `num` have matching rows. The sample data just happens to not have any overlap for this to work.